# Regular expression - move content from tag A to tag B

Tags: php, regex, xml

I need help writing a regular expression that moves content from the title tag into the content tag.

This:

```
<xml>
 <item>
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <content>Text 1</content>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>Title 2</title>
  <content>Text 2</content>
 </item>
</xml>
```

To this:

```
<xml>
 <item>
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <content>Title 1 Text 1</content>
 </item>
 <item>
  <title>Title 2</title>
  <content>Title 2 Text 2</content>
 </item>
</xml>
```

Edit: I made a new topic with a better explaination of my question: [Regular expression - moving content between XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566384/regular-expression-moving-content-between-xml-tags)

SORRY!

Comment: Does it need to be a regex-based solution?

Comment: [Do not parse XML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/695343)

Comment: Do not duplicate your own questions. Instead edit the original one. - I now closed the original question as I already closed the duplicate one. You should make more clear in your question what you tried already so it's more specific with which part you actually have the question. Showing your own code does help in making this more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<title>((?:(?!<\/title>).)*)<\/title>\s*<content>)((?:(?!<\/content>).)*)
```

Try this.Replace by

```
$1$2 $3
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/22

```
$re = "/(<title>((?:(?!<\\/title>).)*)<\\/title>\\s*<content>)((?:(?!<\\/content>).)*)/";
$str = "<xml>\n <item>\n <title>Title 1</title>\n <content>Text 1</content>\n </item>\n <item>\n <title>Title 2</title>\n <content>Text 2</content>\n </item>\n</xml>";
$subst = "$1$2 $3";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: I don't know how to use your regex in preg_replace() can you help me with that?

Comment: @Dylan i have given the full code

Comment: Its not working for me. Here is the XML file: http://bit.ly/1C7NZNv

Comment: @Dylan you will have to store your `xml` in a variable and then apply the code

Comment: I've done that but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using regex for parsing domnodes is bad, there are dom-parsers that help better.
Expressions for matching title tag content:

RegEx with minimal flag (non-greedy, non matching newline):

```
\<title\>(.*)\</title\>
```

RegEx otherwise:

```
\<title\>([^\</title\>]*)\</title\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOTALL` modifier `s` to make dot in your regex to match newline characters also.

Regex:

```
~(<title>([^<>]*)<\/title>.*?<content>)~s
```

Replacement string:

```
\1\2
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL8jC1/3)

```
$re = "/(<title>([^<>]*)<\\/title>.*?<content>)/s";
$str = "<xml>\n <item>\n <title>Title 1</title>\n <content>Text 1</content>\n </item>\n <item>\n <title>Title 2</title>\n <content>Text 2</content>\n </item>\n</xml>";
$subst = "\1\2 ";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```