# Regular expression - moving content between XML tags

Tags: php, regex, xml

I need a regular expression that moves content between XML tags. Here is the markup of the XML file: http://bit.ly/1Gyd1oR

As you can see within a record tag there is a title and content tag. Now I want to replace {title} in the content tag with the content of the title tag.

Comment: Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
It is usually a lot better to use an XML library to manage xml files.

Comment: I've tried a couple of regular expressions but my knowledge is too poor to fix it. Using regular expressions might not be the best solution but I don't really care about that right now. I just want to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$pattern = '#(<record[^>]+><title>([^<]+)</title><content><!\[CDATA\[<html><head><title>)\{title\}#';
$result  = preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $input)
```

But yuck - consider using XML libraries instead.

**Original note (before edit): this regex was originally in Java flavor - I (potame) haven't ran it in PHP.**

Comment: I escaped <\/title> but its not working. edit: thanks for your reply I feel like we're very close to the solution!

Comment: @Dylan: Please read the answer: *"try something like"* - which means you need to modify this, it's just a pointer. It's not meant to work as-is.